# If B is backshift operator, then how to calculate 1/(1 - B)?

Tags: time-series, lags, differences

We have known that:
when |r|<1, (1−r)^-1 = 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + r^4 + . . .
But for 1/(1-B), since the coefficient of B is 1, the power series 1 + B + B^2 + B^3 + . . . can not converge. In my opinion, we can not equal 1/(1-B) with that power series.
So how to calculate 1/(1-B)?

Comment: Just wondering if you mean $1/(1-B)$ or in fact $(1-B)^{-1}$? The  $^{-1}$ means 'inverse' here rather than 'one over'

Comment: Oh, I mean the latter.

Comment: @jcken But I think the two forms are the same. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the sense in which $1+B+B^2+\cdots$ "cannot converge"?  This will give us (and you) useful clues concerning what you are trying to ask by "calculate $1/(1-B).$"

Comment: @whuber Jonas's answer is what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are right. For instance, consider a simple AR(1) process:
\begin{align}
y_t&=\phi_1y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t \quad, \epsilon_t \sim WN(0,\sigma^2) \\
y_t-\phi_1y_{t-1}&=\epsilon_t \\
(1-\phi_1B)y_t&=\epsilon_t \\
\Phi(B)y_t&=\epsilon_t
\end{align}
Where $\Phi(B)=1-\phi_1B$ is the AR-polynomial. If $\vert \phi_1 \vert<1$, this polynomial is invertible, which means that
\begin{align}
\Phi(B)^{-1}=(1-\phi_1B)^{-1}=\frac{1}{1-\phi_1B}=1+\phi_1B+\phi_1B^2+\phi_1^3B^3+\dots
\end{align}
is finite. This is the reason why we can express a stationary AR(1) process as a MA($\infty$) process by simply inverting the AR-polynomial. I think that a simple random walk (the case $\phi_1=1$) corresponds to what you mean with $(1-B)^{-1}$. In this case it is not possible to invert the AR-polynomial, i.e. we cannot calculate $\Phi(B)^{-1}$. You can think of it as  $1+B+B^2+B^3+\dots$ is not finite.

Take a look at Hamilton's book "Time Series Analysis". The first three chapters deal with such type of questions.

Comment: Thank you~ If we can't calculate (1-B)^{-1} , then I think it's impossible for us to convert ARIMA(p,d,q) into infinite MA model. But I learnt from https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/book/export/html/665 that "Any ARIMA model can be converted to an infinite order MA model", which really confused me.

Comment: Your confusion is understandable, since this statement is wrong :D. In general an ARMA(p,q) model has a MA($\infty$) representation if the AR_polynomial is invertible (characteristic roots being all less than 1 in modulus). Otherwise not.

Comment: Yes. But when we want to do interval forecast for the ARIMA,  we need to know the coefficients of MA(∞) in order to calculate the variance, which is contradictory!!